# Entitiy Framework context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand won't save changes to DB

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using EF for my web application and have encountered a strange error. I am trying to update a record in my DB, but even though the `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` call returns 1, when I then call `context.SaveChanges()`, it returns 0 and the changes are not visible in the database.

Here is the code:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    int rows=context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE [Records] SET [ExampleFlag] = 1 WHERE Id in (@ids)",new SqlParameter("@ids",String.Join(",", ids)));
    int rows2 = context.SaveChanges();
}
```

For some reason when debugging, rows equals 1, but rows 2 equals 0. As if it couldn't commit the changes to the database.

Any ideas on what may cause this?

Comment: Any changes made to data in the database using ExecuteSqlCommand are opaque to the context until entities are loaded or reloaded from the database. You can visit this link to refer more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Conversely, `context.SaveChanges()` only saves changes made to objects tracked by the context's change tracker. You didn't modify any object.

Comment: @GertArnold I decided to change my approach and used the Update method which takes the changed object as an input and the changes seem to register properly now. If you put it as an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two ways to write to the database are almost two different worlds.

The core function of an Object-Relational Mapper (ORM) like Entity Framework is to keep an object model (for example in C#) and a relational database model in sync with one another. Therefore it is capable of tracking changes in the object model and writing these changes to the database.

Some ORM's, as a kind of courtesy, offer lower-level APIs to interact with the database. However, these functions don't interact with the ORM function, vise versa.

In other words, whatever statement is executed by `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`, EF's change tracker is completely oblivious of it. If no entity objects were modified by C# code, the change tracker has nothing to do. The executed SQL code has no effect on tracked entity objects.